# Including a company logo in a report

Tags: style, business-writing

There is no "style guide" of any kind for this report, or any reports in this company. Formal reports aren't too frequent. This is a mostly internal report, though it may end up with a consultation rep. The audience is generally my own manager and coworkers, though it is possible it makes it up two or three levels.

This is my situation, which may help refine the answer. But is there any reason I should **not** include the company logo on the cover page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a report generated by your company, you may as well put the logo on it. The only reason not to is if it's literally an internal memo, like an email or something, which isn't really being "distributed." If it's a report, with a title and organization and work which went into it, by all means brand it. It might lend the report a little gravitas, so people *won't* think it's a dashed-off memo.